# J.S not executing all commands

Tags: javascript, html

In the following code, each "Id" is connected to a checkbox, so when I check it a word is printed and if I uncheck it the word disappears.

```
function DrawRequest()
{
    if(document.getElementById("name").checked == true)
        document.getElementById("drawrequest").innerHTML="checked";
    else
        document.getElementById("drawrequest").innerHTML="";
    if(document.getElementById("surname").checked == true)
        document.getElementById("drawrequest").innerHTML="checked";
    else
        document.getElementById("drawrequest").innerHTML="";
    if(document.getElementById("age").checked == true)
        document.getElementById("drawrequest").innerHTML="checked";
    else
        document.getElementById("drawrequest").innerHTML="";
}
```

Or at least that is what should have happened when I tried the code. What really happened is that when I checked the checkbox with id "name" nothing printed. The also happened with the checkbox with id "surname." But the last checkbox with id "age" works fine!

One more question: if the three checkboxes are checked will Ihave three words printed ?
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always update the `innerHTML` for each box, whether it's checked or not.  And each `if` or `else` will overwrite what the previous statements set, making the previous actions irrelevant.

You'll want to either:

- set the innerHTML to blank at the beginning of the function, get rid of the `else`s, and only set the HTML to "checked" if a box is checked (not doing anything if it's unchecked), if you want one "checked" total if any box is checked;
- append to the HTML rather than setting it, if you want a "checked" for each box; or
- Have a separate element to reflect each box's checkedness.